# How can the following code be simplified

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following very repetitive code which I would like to simplify, but struggle because of the property of the `NetworkAdapter` object which is different on each of the event handlers.

What is the best way to do it? Ideally, this should be achieved without lambda expressions, as the client I'm doing this for has little understanding of C# and even less of lambda and they'd be supporting the code when this is done.

```
private void textBoxNetworkSubnetMask_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress.TryParse(textBoxNetworkSubnetMask.Text, out var ipAddress);

    ((NetworkAdapter)comboBoxNetworkCard.SelectedItem).SubnetMask = ipAddress;

    wizardPageNetworkDetails.AllowNext = ValidateNetworkDetailsPage();
}

private void textBoxNetworkGateway_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress.TryParse(textBoxNetworkGateway.Text, out var ipAddress);

    ((NetworkAdapter)comboBoxNetworkCard.SelectedItem).Gateway = ipAddress;

    wizardPageNetworkDetails.AllowNext = ValidateNetworkDetailsPage();
}

private void textBoxNetworkPrimaryDns_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress.TryParse(textBoxNetworkPrimaryDns.Text, out var ipAddress);

    ((NetworkAdapter)comboBoxNetworkCard.SelectedItem).PrimaryDns = ipAddress;

    wizardPageNetworkDetails.AllowNext = ValidateNetworkDetailsPage();
}
```

Comment: If it 'aint broke, don't fix it. Why do you want to simplify it? There's nothing complicated about it, and if your client cannot understand lambdas, they are unlikely to understand anything else you do with it.

Comment: 'cause I have another 15-20 event handlers that suffer from the exact same issue right now and would like to simplify them all.

Comment: A dictionary with delegates perhaps? A huge `switch`/`case` in one method? What is your client up for?

Comment: I'm open minded, including lambdas, but need their approval before implementing it, which is why I sort of tried to steer away from them if possible. Right now what I thought of is setting the Tag of the TextBox to the property to set and then using reflection to set the property. Not quite sure how that'd be better than lambdas but ...

Comment: There's really not much you can do, it's only the third line of code that is shared in each event handler.

Comment: You could have a single event handler that sets up all of the properties of the network adapter, so every textbox change would change every property.

Comment: "what I thought of is setting the Tag of the TextBox to the property to set and then using reflection to set the property" if your client doesn't want lambdas and have little knowledge about C#, you shouldn't think about reflection... the simplest thing to do, afaik, would be a `switch` on the tag, as Sinatr suggested.

Comment: Why are you not checking the result of `TryParse`? You really need to provide us with real code.

Comment: @Enigmativity, because I don't care about it. If `TryParse` fails then `ipAddress == null`, which I check for in `ValidateNetworkDetailsPage()`

Comment: I still wouldn't mind seeing some examples with lambdas though... I said *ideally* no lambdas, doesn't mean I won't consider it or accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: @DavidG that's an option, but feels like slightly messier code than what I already have ...

Comment: Not a solution, just something that may help you develop one: The `sender` paramters is the origin of the event, for all standard components that raise events it is the component. So, you may be able to cast it to `TextBox`. That would make 2 of 3 lines equal among your event handlers. Edit 1: if you can use the `Tag` that can be used to solve the last line. Edit 2: [James's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42413509/402022) does that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code is working and it is asking for a code review. ask codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielA.White I disagree with closing this down as off-topic. It's asking for another way to achieve something, not necessarily code review. We all know there's multiple ways to skin a cat, finding one specific to a particular problem is not, in my opinion code review related.

Comment: @cogumel0 that's the point of codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielA.White but not directly something that's off-topic for stackoverflow.com imho. Else most questions would be off topic too...

Comment: @cogumel0 - That a look at this - [https://dotnetfiddle.net/krYRp0](https://dotnetfiddle.net/krYRp0). Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Enigmativity, that is a way to solve it, but I think I prefer James's answer below (the second one). I've implemented that one now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a single event handler, and change all the "TextChanged" events to use that handler.

ie:

```
private void textBoxIPField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (Textbox)sender;
    IPAddress.TryParse(textBox.Text, out var ipAddress);

    string propertyName = "";
    switch(textBox.Name)
    {
        case textboxNetworkSubnetMask:
            propertyName = "SubnetMask";
            break;
        case textboxNetworkGateway:
            propertyName = "Gateway";
            break;
        case textboxNetworkPrimaryDns:
            propertyName = "PrimaryDns";
            break;
    }
    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(NetworkAdapter).GetProperty(propertyName);
    pi.SetValue((NetworkAdapter)comboBoxNetworkCard.SelectedItem, ipAddress);

    wizardPageNetworkDetails.AllowNext = ValidateNetworkDetailsPage();
}
```

A bit of reflection reduces the amount of code you have to write in switch statements. (make sure you are using `System.Reflection` ) If you are very careful about the textbox naming I guess you could replace the whole switch block with

`propertyName = textBox.Name.Substring(14)`

which would reduce the amount of code, but make it pretty fragile in my opinion. A better option might be to set each textbox's `Tag` value to a PropertyInfo that is the property on the NetworkAdapter class you are interested in within the constructor, and then just refer to that in the above event handler in order to set the property value.

ie `PropertyInfo pi = ((PropertyInfo)textBox.Tag);`

Then the code simplifies to just:

```
//constructor
public MyFormClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //each textbox has a Tag set to the property of a NetworkAdapter that it refers to
    textboxNetworkSubnetMask.Tag = "SubnetMask";
    textboxNetworkGateway.Tag = "Gateway";
    textboxNetworkPrimaryDns.Tag = "PrimaryDns";
}
....

private void textBoxIPField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // (1) determine which textbox we are referring to...
    var textBox = (Textbox)sender;

    // (2) get the IP address that was entered in the textbox
    IPAddress.TryParse(textBox.Text, out var ipAddress);

    // (3) Get the Property of a Network adapter that needs changing.
    // The name of this property was stored in the textbox's Tag in construction.
    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(NetworkAdapter).GetProperty((string)textbox.Tag);

    // (4) Set the new value for that property for the selected NetworkAdapter
    pi.SetValue((NetworkAdapter)comboBoxNetworkCard.SelectedItem, ipAddress);

    wizardPageNetworkDetails.AllowNext = ValidateNetworkDetailsPage();
}
```

That looks simple enough to me. If you want to make sure that someone else can understand it then just comment every line, like I have above. If that's still too hard for them, then I'd question what business they are doing supporting the code in the first place!

Comment: Using the `Tag` property and reflection is exactly what I had already thought of (look at comments in question), but it's great that you put it in an answer. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer see if something else comes through, but if not I'll mark your answer is the correct one.

Comment: I'd make 1 change though: I would use a string on the `Tag` property so that it's visible from the editor and change `(PropertyInfo) textbox.Tag;` to `typeof(NetworkAdapter).GetProperty((string) textbox.Tag)`.

Comment: Ah yes you have! Well I think you already know that succinct (non-repeated) code is usually good code, as you already suggested this. Therefore just make sure its well commented, and feel secure in a job well done.

Comment: @cogumel0 - yeah that seems a reasonable change to me, have changed the code in the answer